# How to properly inherit base class in c++ and override virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm quite new to c++ and I started looking at the SDL2 library to make a simple platformer game. I'm running into a problem with class inheritance. I have a parent class (GameObj) and a child class (Player). When I try to inherit the the GameObj from Player the compiler tells me the base class is undefined. I am trying to override the update function in the Player class, however since I get a "Base class undefined" error it also tells me that the overrode function did not override anything.

**GameObj.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"

class GameObj
{
public:
  GameObj(const char* path);

  ~GameObj();

  virtual void update() = 0;

  void render();

protected:
  SDL_Texture* tex{ nullptr };
  SDL_Rect srcR;
  SDL_Rect dstR;
};
```

**GameObj.cpp**

```
#include "GameObj.h"

GameObj::GameObj(const char* path)
{
  tex = TextureManager::LoadImage(path);

  srcR.x = srcR.y = 0;
  srcR.w = srcR.h = 32 * 2;

  dstR.x = dstR.y = 0;
  dstR.w = dstR.h = srcR.w;
}

GameObj::~GameObj() {}

void GameObj::render() {
  TextureManager::DrawTexture(tex, srcR, dstR);
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"
#include "GameObj.h"

class Player : public GameObj
{
public:
  Player(const char* path, int x, int y);

  ~Player();

  void update() override;

private:
  int x{ 0 };
  int y{ 0 };
  int speed{ 0 };
  int velocity{ 0 };
};
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(const char* path, int x, int y) : GameObj(path){};

Player::~Player() {};

void Player::update () 
{
  x++;

  dstR.x = x;
  dstR.y = y;
}
```

Comment: Since you are including GameObj.h you don't need to forward declare `GameObj` in Player.h. What is the exact copy/pasted error you get when compiling the code shown in your question?

Comment: @RetiredNinja
Error C2504 'GameObj': base class undefined

Comment: What does your file `Game.h` include?

Comment: #ifndef Game_h
`#define Game_h
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include "Player.h"`

Comment: Ah, the old circular include.

Comment: This doesn't fix your issue but just in case no one mentions it make sure you make `GameObj`'s destructor `virtual`. I.e.: `virtual ~GameObj( ) = default`

Comment: I'm just curious but why?

Comment: Lets say you have a destructor in your `Derived` class and didn't have a `virtual` destructor in `GameObj` and then you did something like this: `GameObj* obj = new Derived{ }; delete obj;`. Only the destructor in `GameObj` will be called (the `Derived` classes destructor will not get called). Marking the `GameObj` destructor as `virtual` will prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Retired Ninja commented there is a circular include issue in the code. GameObj.h included Game.h and Game.h included Player.h. To fix this issue I removed the Game.h include in GameObj.h.

**GameObj.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>

class GameObj
{
public:
  GameObj(const char* path);

  virtual ~GameObj() = default;

  virtual void update() = 0;

  void render();

protected:
  SDL_Texture* tex{ nullptr };
  SDL_Rect srcR;
  SDL_Rect dstR;
};
```

**GameObj.cpp**

```
#include "GameObj.h"
#include "TextureManager.h"

GameObj::GameObj(const char* path)
{
  tex = TextureManager::LoadImage(path);

  srcR.x = srcR.y = 0;
  srcR.w = srcR.h = 32 * 2;

  dstR.x = dstR.y = 0;
  dstR.w = dstR.h = srcR.w;
}

GameObj::~GameObj() {}

void GameObj::render() {
  TextureManager::DrawTexture(tex, srcR, dstR);
}
```

Comment: Great to hear that it works. You should also take into account the remark of @WBUCK concerning virtual destructors. It should save you some headaches.

Comment: Looked like the issue was game.h included player.h which included game.h, but I suppose you worked that out if it's working.